# How to dockerize fastText in flask

Tags: python, docker, flask, fasttext

I wrote a simple flask web service to use fastText to do the prediction. I want to put them into docker. My Dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git /tmp/fastText && \
  rm -rf /tmp/fastText/.git* && \
  mv /tmp/fastText/* / && \
  cd / && \
  make


CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.10.0
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  helloworld:
    build:
      context: ./
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

When I run the docker-compose up , it comes with an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fasttext'
```

How to do fix that?

Comment: Try change RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt to RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

Answer (score 1):

Try running those instructions instead of the make one:

```py
$ git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git
$ cd fastText
$ pip install .
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace your Dockerfile with the following:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git && \
    cd fastText && \
    pip install .

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

In this way, you can build fastText for python (as shown [in the official documentation](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/#building-fasttext-for-python)).